# Python: display how old the person is in days and seconds

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python programming and I have problem with my coding as the output doesn't  display age correctly in days and seconds (as shown on 'output' below)

### Output

```
Please enter your birthday
Year:1985
Month (1-12):5
Date:8
Your age is 10024 days, 0:00:00
```

Can anyone assist further why and how to fix this problem?

### Code

```
print "Please enter your birthday "
bd_y=int(input("Year:"))
bd_m=int(input("Month (1-12):"))
bd_d=int(input("Date:"))

from datetime import date
now = date.today ()

age = date(int(bd_y), int(bd_m), int(bd_d))
print ("Your age is " + str(now-age))
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: At the beginning you're using the print statement (python 2.x) and on the end you're using the print function(python 3.x), you should fix that.

Comment: @tehmisvh It's actually not a problem. It's ok to add the extra parenthesis to a `print` statement. I can only see a problem here if one tries to run this on Python 3, which wasn't the issue here.

Comment: What would be the output you expect? For me it seems the program works just alright.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: To display the age with seconds precision you obviously need to know their exact birth time, not just a birthdate. Otherwise you assume everyone to be born at midnight.

Comment: @jsalonen that is correct, but it's confusing to look at, especially because of him using input(), which are two different things in python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Oh right. I get your point now!

Answer (score 8):

`datetime.date` only tracks year, month, and days.  If you want the time as well you should use [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime.now() - datetime(1985, 5, 8))
'10024 days, 8:51:08.441714'
```

The result of the subtraction is a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object, which has the attributes `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds` for customizing output:

```
>>> delta = datetime.now() - datetime(1985, 5, 8)
>>> print "Your age is %d days and %d seconds" % (delta.days, delta.seconds)
Your age is 10024 days and 32125 seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `datetime` instead of `date`.

Make sure you change the import too.

Answer (score 2):

The following works. You were converted to an int() twice, but that isn't what would break it.

I would suggest switching to datetime as suggested, but below is working with what you provided.

```
print "Please enter your birthday"
bd_y = input("Year: ")
bd_m = input("Month (1-12): ")
bd_d = input("Date: ")

from datetime import date
now = date.today()

birthdate = date(int(bd_y), int(bd_m), int(bd_d))

age =  now-birthdate

print "Your age is %s" % age
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("please enter your birthday")
bd_y=int(input("Year:"))
bd_m=int(input("Month(1-12):")) 
bd_d=int(input("Date:"))
from datetime import date
now = date.today ()

age = date(int(bd_y),int(bd_m), int(bd_d))
print ("your age is " +str(now-age))
```

Comment: What has been changed? It seems as copied code from the question.